# Having Issues in calculating Sum of digits in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a task to calculate sum of digits in C#. In this case as an example. I like to calculate the sum of "12345" which is: 1+2+3+4+5 = 15. But the result coming after the execution of code is: 53. What is the mistake in the code?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputNumber = "12345";

    int sum =0;
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Desired Number");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inputNumber[i]);
        sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(inputNumber[i]);

        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output your are getting for this line: ```Console.WriteLine(inputNumber[i]);```?

Comment: Compare the output of `Convert.ToInt32(1)` with that of `Convert.ToInt32('1')`.

Comment: Just call the tostring before converting the char to int: sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(inputNumber[i].ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Converting a `char` to an `int` is not the same as converting a `string` to an `int` For `char`, the ASCII value is used.

```
sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(inputNumber[i].ToString());
```

If you convert your `char` to a `string`, it will do what you expect it to do.

Comment: I would add that if you want to be sure you could use `Int32.Parse()` as it would throw an error if you try to enter a char.

Comment: @vvilin: I'm on the fence about that approach. Not that it doesn't work, but `Convert.ToFoo` is generally nicer to use than `Foo.Parse`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It has helped me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that "Convert.ToInt32" is returning the ascii value and you are looking for the numeric value, your code could be like this:

```
sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(inputNumber[i]));
```

for more information about GetNumericValue here is a link:
[get numeric value msdn](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score -2):

Sorry wrong answer.

This is the problem:

```
Convert.ToInt32(inputNumber[i].ToString());
```

If you don't cast it to string, it's a char.
And convert a char to int will give its ASCII value.